Send an object of derived class from Angular to a function that takes base class in C#
I have in C# a class App_Mail that inherits from the class App_action
then I have a function that recieves an object of type App_Action
I want to send from angular an object of type App_Mail to the function in C#
When I send the Object - the function recognizes it as App_Action and ommits the extra attributes that are part of app_mail class.
This is my code:
C#:
   public class APP_Action
    {
        public string ActionID { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }

public class APP_Mail:APP_Action
    {
        public string? FromDisplayName { get; set; }
        public string? MailSubject { get; set; }
        public string? MailBody { get; set; }
    }

 public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] APP_Action entity)
    {
     var a=entity.GetType();//returnes APP_Action
    }

Now I am sending an object tof type APP_Mail, what can I do so that the C# recognizes that the object recieved is of the derived class?


Now I am sending an object tof type APP_Mail, what can I do so that the C# recognizes that the object recieved is of the derived class?

Change the method signature to:
public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] APP_Mail entity)

The object is being instantiated by the framework via reflection; the method signature is used to work out what type to instantiate.

no, I want it to be of type APP_Action, so I can send also other classes that are derived from APP_Action

@more21: Then I believe you'll need a different architecture (e.g. posting different types to different URLs). How would you expect the framework to know which class to instantiate? Do you include any sort of "type marker" in the JSON? Look at what's coming across the wire in the request, and ask yourself how you expect the framework to know what to do with that.

@more21: Also note that I answered the question as you asked it. What you've specified now is an additional requirement which isn't in the question. Please, please don't "trickle feed" requirements - it's a really frustrating experience for someone trying to help you.

@more21: Another option might be to accept the "raw" JSON (e.g. a System.Text.Json.JsonDocument) and then work out which type to deserialize it to yourself.

Ok, I guess I'll use your first idea - and just create seperate urls, thanks for your help!
